# Normal Distrubution Question - How many components are defective and acceptable?

Tags: normal-distribution

> A component is defective if oversized. A sample of 460 components produced by a machine have a mean size of 7.2 cm and a standard deviation of 0.12 cm. The maximum size of an acceptable component is 7.46 cm. Assume a normal distribution.

(i) Determine how many components are defective.

(ii) Find how many components are acceptable.

Acceptable components:

$$P(X ≤ 7.46)$$
$$P(Z ≤ \frac{7.46-7.2}{0.12})$$
$$P(Z ≤ 2.17)$$
$$0.9850$$
$$0.9850*460$$
$$453$$

Defective components:

$$460 - 453 = 7$$

This seemed a bit to simple to me as I have been having a lot of trouble with these, is this correct?

Comment: Have you reprinted the problem faithfully?  As stated, it can't be answered.  It is perfectly possible (if highly improbable) that every single sample will be defective.  You have correctly computed the cumulative probability for size $≤7.46$) but for an actual sample all you can compute are probabilities.

Comment: I double checked it there and it's exactly the same. I calculated the acceptable components 1st, which worked out to be 453, then took that from 460 since the rest would be defective.

Comment: As I said, your have correctly computed the number assuming that the normal distribution holds.  And $460$ is pretty large so it isn't a crazy assumption that it holds here...but it is still perfectly possible for it not to hold.  For instance, it should not surprise you to see $6$ or $8$ defective units.  You can use a binomial distribution to compute probabilities for any particular number of defective units.

Comment: I just ran a few numbers using the binomial distribution (with a probability of "success", i.e. defect,  of $p=0.01513014$ which is what the normal distribution gives).  For $7$ defects I see a probability of $0.150131573$ but $6$ is actually slightly higher, at $0.150678095$.  $8$ has probability $0.130600353$ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I do not believe this problem can be solved as stated.  A sample is just a sample and might well fail to perfectly respect the properties of the underlying distribution.

To be more precise:  Let $p$ be the probability that a given unit is defective.  using the given normal distribution we see that $$p\sim 0.01513014$$

(Note:  the OP's calculation gives $p=.015$ which is, of course, the same value with fewer significant places).

We can now use the binomial distribution to compute the probability, $p_k$, of getting exactly $k$ defective units.  In general, of course, we have $$p_k=\binom {460}k\times p^k\times (1-p)^{460-k}$$

This is easy to compute, at least with mechanical assistance.  The first few values are $$p_0=0.000900056,\,p_1=0.006360504,\,p_2=0.022425302,\,p_3=0.052595263$$ $$p_4=0.092313866,\,p_5=0.129337921,\,p_6=0.150678095,\,p_7=0.150131573,$$$$p_8=0.130600353,\,p_9=0.100763762,\,p_{10}=0.069814401,\,p_{11}=0.043876194$$ $$p_{12}=0.025220758,\,p_{13}=0.013352325,\,p_{14}=0.006549385,p_{15}=0.002991632$$ $$p_{16}=0.00127824$$

Collectively, that covers more than $99.9\%$ of the cases.  We note that $7$ is not even the most probable (though it is very close).

Also worth noting:  even if you "broaden the definition of $7$" to include $6,8$ it is still more likely than not that your actual sample will fall outside this strip.

Comment: Thank you for putting so much effort into this, perhaps this problem is a bit incorrect, I pulled it from an old exam paper, I thought it made sense till you mentioned this.

Comment: It may well be that they intended the answer you wrote...but, as you can see, I don't think that answer describes the situation very well.